# Swift type conformance to Any

Tags: swift

Does every type in swift, apart from functions, conform to `Any`? I understand that `AnyObject` represents all class types and `Any` is at a higher level than that, representing all other types. However I came across a situation recently where I had a function that looked like:

```
func myFunFunction(someArgument: Any) {
    ...
}
```

And when calling it with a `String` argument: `myFunFunction("This is a string")` I get an error saying that type `String` can't be converted to type `Any`.

Edit:

The above example is just that, an example. I wanted to simplify the code just to get an answer but here's my actual code:

I have a class `final class CollectionViewBinder: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate { }`
that serves as a collection view binding helper for ReactiveCocoa.

The init method:

```
init(collectionView: UICollectionView, dataSignal: SignalProducer<[[Any]], NoError>, supplementarySignal: SignalProducer<[[Any]], NoError>?) { ... }
```

If the type of `dataSignal` is `SignalProducer<[[String]], NoError>`, that's when I get the error saying type `SignalProducer<[[String]], NoError>` can't be converted to type `SignalProducer<[[Any]], NoError>` which would lead me to think my error is something to do with ReactiveCocoa possibly?

Comment: "Does every type in swift, apart from functions, conform to Any" No. Every type in Swift, _including_ functions, conforms to Any.

Comment: In a playground, I can call `myFunFunction("a string")` without any errors. It might help if you show the actual code. Swift error messages can be misleading, and the actual error is often on a different line or caused by a different reason.

Comment: I updated with more code.

Comment: So your actual problem seems to be that an array of String can not be passed as an array of Any argument. That would be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954358/swift-2-2-cannot-convert-value-of-type-b-to-specified-type-a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you expect is called "generic covariance" and is currently not supported by Swift.

https://nomothetis.svbtle.com/type-variance-in-swift

Answer (score 2):

You are right about `Any`, apple docs say:

> Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.

The example you gave works for me without any problems. Usually in this kind of situations the error is in some other place but the compiler gives a misleading message.